# Correct place to initialize the data in angular

Tags: angular, angular9

I need a expert advice to know that, where can i initialize my variable in angular? is in `constructor` or `ngOnInit` ? or both?

here the code :
option => 1

```
constructor() {
this.name = 'Test Stock Company';
this.code = 'TSC';
this.price = 85;
this.previousPrice = 80;
this.positiveChange = this.price >= this.previousPrice;
this.favorite = false;
}
```

option => 2

```
ngOnInit() {
this.name = 'Test Stock Company';
this.code = 'TSC';
this.price = 85;
this.previousPrice = 80;
this.positiveChange = this.price >= this.previousPrice;
this.favorite = false;
}
```

Or how the impacts if both are mixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always use `ngOnInit` because it belongs to Angular component lifecycle. In `ngOnInit` you have access to `@Input` variables. You can trigger `ngOnInit` during writing tests by `fixture.detectChanges()`.

On the other hand constructor is not related with Angular, it is a part of TypeScript/JavaScript language. Ctors should only be used to inject services like in many other languages.